# How to solve this valgrind issue?

Tags: android, valgrind

I'm trying to run valgrind on an android OS but it couldn't start and it shows this errors that i couldn't find how to solve:

```
valgrind: Startup or configuration error:
Can't create client cmdline file in /tmp/valgrind_proc_87_cmdline_876a7612
valgrind: Unable to start up properly.  Giving up.
```

Thanks in advance !

I tried to change the default path that valgrind use and which is shown on the error log but i couldn't make it

Comment: does it have permission to write to `/tmp` folder?

Comment: there is no /tmp folder on my system that's why am searching how to refer it to an other folder

Comment: @Shark I had same problem even giving changin /tmp permission with `chmod -R 777 /tmp`

Comment: what happens when you create the folder, make it writable and then try again? could it be a permission-related thing perhaps?

Comment: How did you manage to build valgrind for Android?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is happening in the code where the Valgrind host is creating a fake `/proc/<pid>/cmdline.`

This file should be created in the location given by the first valid item in the following list:

- The TMPDIR environment variable
- The constant VG_TMPDIR that gets baked into the binary via a configure time option. This defaults to `/tmp` but can be overriden using `configure --with-tmpdir=/your/tmp/dir`. That would require that you get the Valgrind source and configure and build it. It is possible that you are using a package that was built using this option and is not compatible with your system.
- Last resort, "/tmp"

All of the above checks just test that the string is non-null and not empty. They do not test for the existance and accessibility of the directory. That gets determined by the Valgrind version of `mkstemp` and the error message comes from 'valgrind_main'.

Valgrind needs to create a file TMPDIR/valgrind_proc_PID_cmdline_RAND where TMPDIR is described above, PID is the pid of the Valgrind process and RAND is a random number.

There is at least one other similar files that get created, for auxv.

There are no Valgrind command line options to turn off the creation of these files.